# Callback function in flutter from child to parent class

Tags: flutter, dart, callback

I am new to Flutter.
I have three classes, the first one is the Home Screen and the second one is from the SDK that is used to call the API through a function in the third class.

I want to go to the second screen from the Home Screen and there I have to call the API function from the third class.

After calling the API, I have to come back to the second screen where I am waiting for the response. I have to pass this response to the Home Screen.

After calling the API function, I will take the user to the Home Screen immediately.

> I have to get the response at the Home Screen after the API will return it.
> ApiMethods is in the third class and apiRequest is its function that is calling and returning the response of the API.

```
            ApiMethods().apiRequest().then((response) {
              //controller will come here after getting response
              //here should be a callback that will take response to homeScreen
            });

             //going immediately back to home screen after calling API
            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => userHome),
                    (route) => false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, userHome)`.

Comment: It will pop all classes and will take me to the named class, but my question is about callback to get response at home screen.